# Change RStudio default browser for markdown on Mac

Tags: r, browser, rstudio, r-markdown

I changed the default app that opens HTML files to Atom.
Now the button 'Open in browser' of the RStudio knitted HTML markdown brings me to Atom.

How can I set it to bring me back to Safari forever without switching back the HTML editor?

P.S. do you have any suggestion for the workflow?

Comment: Have you tried setting the `BROWSER` environment variable before starting RStudio?

Comment: @user2554330  What do you mean _before_ starting RStudio? I changed it _from_ the RStudio console and it works in most of the cases like the help search (also I liked that in the RStudio browser), but not on the knitted HTLM.

Comment: If you were starting RStudio from a bash console, you'd do `BROWSER=safari rstudio` (with suitable replacements for `safari` and `rstudio`).  I don't know how to do the equivalent if you start it from the Finder, but presumably you can.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I tried but the environment variable seems to not affect that button.